# How to append (line no. * 4 ) in each line using awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed

I have `mb0.h` has some hex numbers

```
B0000000
B80806B0
B0000000
```

so on...

I have appended below texts using cmd below:

```
sed -i 's/\$/);/' ../mb0.h
sed -i 's/^/PS_Out(TILE_ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, /' ../mb0.h
```

This has generated the text shown below -

```
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, B0000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, B8080050);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, B0000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, B8080954);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, B0000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, B80806B0);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, 00000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, 00000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+, B0000000);
```

so on ...

**I want the Output as -** 0 , 4, 8 .... 4*(line no. -1) appended below as shown in the bold.

```
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+0, B0000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+4, B8080050);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+8, B0000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+12, B8080954);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+16, B0000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+20, B80806B0);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+24, 00000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+28, 00000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+32, B0000000);
```

so on ...

I am generating input file text using sed but not sure if i can insert numbers after pattern match using sed itself or if possible using awk command.
Please help with the solution -

Comment: It's good that you provided sample input, expected output, and your code but a) you can't get the output you show from the input you show as the values are different, and b) you can't get the output you say you do from the code you posted as you're escaping `$` in the first script so it won't append `);` and printing `TILE_` in the second script. When asking questions please show the actual code you're running and make sure the output you show is the output for the input you show, not some different output, so your requirements are clear and we can copy/paste your example as-is to test with.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial in `awk`:

```
awk '{print "PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+"(NR-1)*4", "$0");"}' ../mb0.h
```

For inplace editing, like with GNU `sed`'s `-i`, you can use `-i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹ with GNU `awk`, or switch to `perl` (where GNU `sed` copied that `-i` from):

```
perl -i -lne 'print "PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+", ($.-1)*4, ", $_);"' ../mb0.h
```

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Done with below steps

```
i=0
awk -v i="$i" '{print "PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+"i", "$1");";i=i+4}' file1.txt
```

output

```
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+0, B0000000);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+4, B80806B0);
PS_Out(ADDR(0,0)+0x00020000+8, B0000000);
```